# Python Downloading Zip Files Damaged

Tags: python, download, urllib2

So, I've been trying to make a simple downloader that downloads my zip file.

Code looks like this:

```
import urllib2
import os
import shutil

url = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/29251693/CreeperCraft.zip"

file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
f = open('c:\CreeperCraft.zip', 'w+')
meta = u.info()

file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)

file_size_dl = 0
block_sz = 8192
while True:
    buffer = u.read(block_sz)
    if not buffer:
        break

    file_size_dl += len(buffer)
    f.write(buffer)
    status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (file_size_dl, file_size_dl * 100. / file_size)
    status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
    print status,

f.close()
```

And the problem is, it downloads the file to the correct path, but when I open the file, its damaged, only 1 picture appears and when you click on it, it says `File Damaged`.

Please help.

Answer (score 9):

```
f = open('c:\CreeperCraft.zip', 'wb+')
```

Comment: Exactly. Zip files are binary, not text. Too bad the default mode for opening a file isn't binary.

Comment: I had the same problem and thought it was caused by my Content-Type or Accept headers. I had no clue (until I read this answer) that it was my file "open" line that wasn't encoding my file as it needed to be.

Comment: Awesome, worked for me. I had used wb, and initially the code worked fine (weird) but one day it stopped working. That's when changing it to wb+ made it work again.

Answer (score 2):

You are using "w+" as flag, Python opens the file in *text* mode:

> Python on Windows makes a distinction between text and binary files;
>   the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered
>   slightly when data is read or written. This behind-the-scenes
>   modification to file data is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll
>   corrupt binary data like that in JPEG or EXE files.

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Also, note that you should escape the backslash or use raw strings, therefore use  `open('c:\\CreeperCraft.zip', 'wb+')`.

I also would recommend that you do not copy raw byte strings by hand, but use `shutil.copyfileobj` - it makes your code more compact and easier to understand. I also like to use the `with` statement that automatically cleans up resources (i.e. that closes files:

```
import urllib2, shutil

url = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/29251693/CreeperCraft.zip"
with urllib2.urlopen(url) as source, open('c:\CreeperCraft.zip', 'w+b') as target:
  shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
```

Comment: wb+ fixed it, thx!, but i dont understand the other code u gave me... But anyway, it works!!

Answer (score 1):

```
import posixpath
import sys
import urlparse
import urllib

url = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/29251693/CreeperCraft.zip"
filename = posixpath.basename(urlparse.urlsplit(url).path)
def print_download_status(block_count, block_size, total_size):
    sys.stderr.write('\r%10s bytes of %s' % (block_count*block_size, total_size))
filename, headers = urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename, print_download_status)
```